# Writing to Hive with target table being driven from columns in data

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have DataSet with uber schema and the requirement is to write to different Hive table depending on some column values. Basically, the combined column values determine the target Hive table. I thought about using groupBy but the result is for aggregation and using repartition doesn't always guarantee one partition maps to one Hive table. Any other options?

Comment: one option is to collect your column information into List.  iterate over the list  do filter on your uber df to filter only the relevant records and send that DF to your write method.

Comment: @Aaron, yes this is our current method after making this post. The current logic loops over all possible schemas, filter accordingly and writes to target table. I guess this solution is feasible given the number of schemas is small (< 20).